# Carregar JS antes de renderizar a pagina

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Boa tarde,

Tenho um codigo de `php` onde tem uma lista de publicações e ele utiliza o `Ajax`, mas infelizmente ele está sendo o ultimo a ser baixado pela pagina.

Depois de todos os arquivos que tem dentro do `while`, e está fazendo com que o `Ajax` não funcione corretamente..

**Dúvida:** Existe forma de importar o JS antes de qualquer load?

Tentei pela tag *Defer* e *Async* do `HTML5` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Coloque seu código HTML e onde está referenciando o código pra gente poder te ajudar

Comment: Se você não quer que a resposta seja assíncrona, por que utilizar AJAX? Por que já não entrega todos os dados na resposta HTTP com o PHP?

Comment: Boa leitura https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/ mas procure tb em outras fontes!

Comment: @VictorLaio o código é bem grande para colocar aqui, tentei carregar assincrono, mas nao deu diferença http://prntscr.com/m5g24c

Comment: Sem o código nao tem como te ajudar amigo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Acredito que uma boa abordagem junto a chamada do javascript logo depois da tag Head é utilizar em seu arquivo JS uma estrutura IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression),
Desta forma você estará auto-executando sua função. Mais informações podem ser vistas aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/IIFE

Answer (score 0):

Basta você colocar o código Javascript ou o link dele logo depois da tag Head.

A pagina sempre espera que o script seja carregado e verificado antes de continuar a carregar todos os outros elementos abaixo dele.